# No Bracha Before Yes after

Tags: riddle, blessing, food

When are you forbidden from making a Brocha Rishona on a food item,and obligated to make
a Bracha Achrona after eating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earlier answers may be right but not what i was looking for.

The **Mishna Berurah** in Siman 196 s”k 4 says that if you steal wheat and grind it into flour, although he is required to return it. Hallachicly he is its new owner, nevertheless he may not, make a brocha on food produced from that stolen wheat.The reason for this is based in the concept of “Ein zeh Mevareich elah menaeitz”(he’s not blessing, rather he is being disgusting).  This concept is only true for Brocha Rishona; as far as the Bracha achrona is concerned, if one made bread out of stolen wheat and ate to the point of satiation, since he’s now obligated from the Torah to say Birkas Hamazon, he is not absolved of his obligation, and he still has too ‘bentch’.

Comment: No one actually holds that that is the halacha.  The MB brings a machlokes- some say make both brachos, some say make neither.  The MB then quotes (part of) the Magen Avraham that, if you ate to satiation so that its a d'oraysa question, you should be machmir to bentch.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, but probably not what you wanted: most food during a meal. They don't require a Brocho Rishonah, and definitely require a Bracha Achronah.

Otherwise, something keeps nagging at my brain like I know it, but just can't place it.

Comment: This is not counting _hamotzi_ as the _b'racha rishona_ on food during the meal, but is counting _birkas hamazon_ as its _b'racha acharona_. On what basis, please?

Comment: Well he never said anything about "counting". Just "forbidden" - which is true, and "obligated" - which is also true. Taking into context that this was asked as a riddle, it would certainly fit.

Comment: You're correct though. If I count it for one I should count it for the other.... Just the way he phrased it.

Comment: Good point (re "he never said... asked as a riddle...").

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but, as a guess, something that must be eaten immediately to save a life (e.g., of someone starving).